# batch rename files on date

Tags: batch-file, terminal, rename

I rendered 140000 frames to create a movie of them.
However, it starts at 1.png where it would be better if it had started at 000001.png in order to keep the order good when importing it in final cut express.

I used to have a program r-name but that was based on power-pc so it doesn't work anymore.
Also the program was quite shit with even a batch of 300 files for example so i guess it would be better to use the terminal for that.

I have seen examples for renaming but most where for changing the extention for example or change a prefix.

Could someone help me with the right terminal script? I need to finish this project asap, else i would have re-rendered it but it takes 15 hours to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in *.png
do
    name=${i%.png}
    [[ $name =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && mv $i "$(printf '%06d' $name).png"
done
```

Comment: must i type this in 1 time or hit return after every line?

Comment: You can put all in one line sep by `;`

Answer (score 2):

Not very efficient, but since you need to run it only once:

```
for i in `seq 1 140000`; do
  mv $i.png `printf %06d $i`.png
done
```

**EDIT:** I assumed (maybe wrongly) that you were using Linux. This won't work on Windows.

**EDIT:** Yes, this should work in Mac OS X. Instead of typing these lines into the prompt, you can save it to a file. Usually, you would save such a file with a name like `rename.sh`. Then You can run it on the terminal like this:

```
sh rename.sh
```

If you are unsure, you can change the `mv` line into:

```
echo mv $i.png `printf %06d $i`.png
```

This will print out on the screen the commands that would be executed. Then if everything looks ok, you change it back to the original and run it again.

If the number of files is different, just replace `140000` with the number of the last file.

Comment: i use mac os x, so this must work right?
I checked, finder says it are 121596 files exactly, but when i copy paste to another dit it's something in the 140000 (a bit more) so what must i do with the 140000 in your script?
Also must i type this as one line or in 3 times?

Comment: I flagged kev's answer as the accepted cause his one is cleaner and i think it's important for the quality of stackoverflow to choose based on that. (and i used his lines). However you where a really great help in all this so thanks for that. Wish i could flag 2 answers...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*.png) do (
  set "name=00000%%~nF"
  ren "%%F" "!name:~-6!.png"
)
```